# Unable to import data as numeric from Excel file

Tags: excel, formatting, sqldatatypes, dbeaver, negative-number

In Dbeaver, I'm trying to automate the importing of an excel spreadsheet into a table. The problem is with the datatypes. The source excel file is using parentheses for negative numbers instead of a -. (example - excel shows (1,234) database needs -1,234) During the import, because I've set the column to a numeric datatype, it errors out on the first parenthesis it finds.

***Error occurred during data load
Reason:
Can't parse numeric value [(10,460)] using formatter***

The details button reveals:

***Can't parse numeric value [(10,460)] using formatter
Character ( is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark***

Obvious answer is to modify the excel file, but I can't. I've looked all over Dbeaver for options to transform the numbers as they're imported, replacing the parens with a single -. But no such luck.

Are there any solutions/workarounds that aren't going to make me insane? (*More insane)